# loop of for isn't working when using object and dynamic array(created using pointers) or maybe vector

Tags: c++

the second loop in the main body stops after just one step. I don't know why!
my code {

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <vector> // using dynamic array

using namespace std;

int i; // for loops

class person{
    private:
        string name; // the name of the person
        vector < string > ne; // the names that are in the list
        int mn_f; // the money at the first before giving to other people
        int n; // the number of people in the list
        int mn_l = 0; // the money at the end of the party
    public:
        void set_name(string name){ // setting the name
            this -> name = name;
        }
        string get_name(){ // returning the name
            return name;
        }
        void set_mn_f(int mn_f){ // getting the first money of the person
            this -> mn_f = mn_f;
        }
        void set_n(int n){ // getting the n
            this -> n = n;
        }
        void set_list(){ // getting the people that are in the list
            string a; // a member in the list
            for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
                cin >> a;
                ne.push_back(a);
            }
            //cout << "started\n";  
        }
        void get_list(){
            for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
                cout << i + 1 << ' ' << ne[i] << endl;
            }
            //cout << "finished\n";
        }
        void mod(){
            mn_l += (mn_f % n); // the mod of money to the n is for the person
        }
        void set_mn_l(int n){ // calculating the last money of the person
            mn_l += n;
        }
        int get_mn_l(){
            return mn_l; // returning the last money of the person
        }
        ~person(){
            ne.clear(); // deleting ne
        }
};

int main(){
    int n; // the number of attendees
    string ne; // name of the people
    cin >> n;
    person Person; // the person and its information
    vector < person > a; // the list of the people in the party
    int mn_f; // the money at the first before giving to other people
    int nu; // the number of people in the list
    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cin >> ne; // entering the names for the first time
    }
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++){ // entering the names for the second time and completing the information
        cin >> ne >> mn_f >> nu;        
        Person.set_name(ne); // name
        Person.set_mn_f(mn_f); // money at first
        Person.set_n(nu); // the number of the people in the list of Person
        Person.set_list(); // entering the people in the list
        a.push_back(Person); // putting the Person in the list
        cout << "loop\n";
    }
    cout << a.size() << endl;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Person = a[i];
        cout << Person.get_name() << endl;
        Person.get_list();
        cout << "loop2\n";
    }
    cout << a.size() << endl;
    a.clear(); // deleting a
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Define a constructor and an assignment operator to properly copy the dynamic array instead of simply copying the pointer to cause double-free or use-after-free problem.

Comment: Or better, follow the Rule of Zero by replacing that `string *` with `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: This code is doubly-tangled.  Copies of a `person` will share the same `ne` pointer, with the first destructor deleting it.  But `set_n_and_list()` will overwrite `ne` without deleting what it may currently point to, potentially leaking.  Consider what @Yksisarvinen suggested and don't use raw pointers at your current skill level.  Your program _"stops after just one step"_ because it likely crashed.

Comment: As others pointed out, you must be very careful with pointers. Using a vector will likely remove your problem. In the future, learn about smart pointers. Just one suggestion on your code: keep related things together. You have a main where you get your data with cin, and then you have a class where you hid another interaction with cin. It would be simpler to build and understand if all your input process is handled in the main, and Person only receives and returns values.

Comment: I used vector but still the loops aren't working and they stop after just 1 step

Comment: have you tried testing or debugging your code with hardcoded values instead of using `cin`?